# Python error: Can't convert bytes to string implicitly

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, server

I'm programming a basic chat program. The goal of this is first to set up the server by launching the server.py script then leave that running in the background. Then a user launches the client.py script and chooses a name then starts to type a message and send it. The problem is when I attempt to send it it returns this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\client.py", line 38, in <module>
    s.sendto(alias + ': ' + message.encode() , server)
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Here's the server.py script ---

```
import socket
import time

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 47015

clients = []
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.setblocking(0)

qutting = False
print("Server Started")

while not qutting:
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        if 'Quit' in str(data):
            qutting = True
        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)
        print(time.ctime(time.time()) + str(addr) + ": :" + str(data))
        for client in clients:
            s.sendto(data, client)
    except:
        pass
s.close()
```

**then the client.py script----**

```
import socket
import threading
import time


tLock = threading.Lock()
shutdown = False

def recieving(name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            tLock.acquire()
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                data.decode()
                print(str(data))
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            tLock.release()

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 0

server = ("127.0.0.1", 47015)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.setblocking(0)

rT = threading.Thread(target=recieving, args=('RecvThread', s))
rT.start()

alias = input("Name: ")
message = input(alias + "->")
while message != 'q':
    if message != '':
        s.sendto(alias + ': ' + message.encode() , server)
    tLock.acquire()
    message = input(alias + '->')
    tLock.release()
    time.sleep(0.2)

shutdown = True
rT.join()
s.close()
```

So if you have any idea how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated also a side question is would there be a way to make it so that the receiving thread runs all the time so it actively updates the chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
s.sendto(alias + ': ' + message.encode() , server)
```

You are converting `message` to a `bytes`, but then you are adding unconverted strings to the `bytes` object. This is an invalid operation, as the error message is telling you, because the `bytes` can not be unambiguously converted to a string. Try to encode the whole thing:

```
s.sendto((alias + ': ' + message).encode() , server)
```